# JPanel remove color gradient

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have the following problem:

I have my own instance of JPanel to create an ImageButton.
When I set a background, it automatically adds a color gradient, which causes the transparent image to have a background that doesn't fit the color of my JFrame.

How can I remove this gradient?

```
public ImageButton(Runnable exec, boolean on) {
        super();

        setBackground(new Color(238,238,238));
        setVisible(false);
        switched_on = on;
        setSize(new Dimension(64, 64));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(64, 64));
        if(on) {
            img = ImageButton.on;
        }else{
            img = ImageButton.off;
        }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Screenshot: ImageButton

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hen6K.png]

Another Screenshot, where you see the gradient better

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8eFl.png]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 3) `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I tried to find this error inside my source, but instead, the image itself has a whitish background in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2):

> When I set a background, it automatically adds a color gradient, which causes the transparent image to have a background that doesn't fit the color of my JFrame.

Make the panel transparent:

```
setOpaque( false );
```

Now both the image and the panel will be transparent so the background color will be the background of the parent component of your ImagePanel.

Although an easier approach is to just use a `JLabel`. A `JLabel` is transparent by default. Then you can just use the `setIcon(...)` method to change the image. So there is no need for custom painting or a custom component.